# Remove applied CSS transformation

Tags: html, css

I have applied `-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);` to flip an image. I am applying              -`webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);` to rotate it back to original position. Now I have some other classes to be applied, but when I check in Chrome Inspect Element I can see that `rotateY(0)` is still there which should be completely removed.

How can I remove the animation completely from an Element?

```css
.transition
{
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.notransition {
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);
  transform:rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Take the class away from that element

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9rnbN/1/)?

Comment: did the answer help you? accept the answer if it has helping you, or post your own answer.

Comment: Can you try transform=‘none’?

Answer (score 50):

just do this:

```
.transition {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.notransition {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
```

[`none` seems to be the default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: But what if I added both rotation and translation and would like to remove only one of them? E.g. I want to remove only rotation. Should I compute the undo value for the rotation and apply it in css then or is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: transform accepts comma separated values, the order you specify both properties, is also the order you disable the properties.
`.transition { transform: rotateY(180deg), rotateX(180deg); }`
`.notransition { transform: none, rotateX(180deg); }`

Comment: Very important and useful. Thank you. Could you, please, provide a source which taught you this?

Comment: I correct my previous comment, it's not comma separated, it's space separated, background properties are comma separated.
More info: here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 9):

```css
.transition {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.notransition {
    -webkit-transform:unset;
    transform:unset;
}
```

Comment: Before answer the question, kindly check wtih the other answers. Don't post duplicate answers.

Comment: i have checked other answer and find incorrect because none is not working with transform, so before comment check all answer.

Comment: not sure why you have the downvote, but the 'unset' works for me

Comment: none is the default keyword: please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 1):

In my case i needed a way to `override` an inline `transform` that was being setted by third party component and i didn't want it to remove it manually.

According to [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), you can only transform elements:

> Only transformable elements can be transformed. That is, all elements
> whose layout is governed by the CSS box model except for: non-replaced
> inline boxes, table-column boxes, and table-column-group boxes.

So, you can disable transform by just modifing display to a non-element one, I changed it to `display:inline` so the transform stops working:

```css
.transition {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
    
.notransition {
    display: inline;
}
```

Of course this will mess up with animation, however it's usefull when you are working with responsive CSS:

```css
// small resolution / animation will stop working, and element will expand to the whole screen
.transition {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.notransition {
    display: inline;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

// medium resolution / animation works
@media print, screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    .notransition {
       -webkit-transform:unset;
        transform:unset;
    }
}
```