# box with skew and background image

Tags: html, css, transform, skew

The image that I want to put inside the boxes is skewed in the same way as the boxes are. I want the images to not get skewed as the boxes are. The problem is that I've set `skew(-20deg)` to the boxes, and when I set `skew(20deg)` on the image, it wont work. The image wont stand up straight. Any solutions?

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: #FFAE00;
}

.accordion ul {
  width: 90%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 100%;
}

.accordion ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 250px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  float: none;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

.accordion ul li div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion ul li div a {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 37vw;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 55px 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: -53px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.accordion ul li div a * {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion ul li div a h2 {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-overflow: clip;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: unset;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  top: 165px;
}

.accordion ul li div a p {
  top: 165px;
  font-size: 13.5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("http://michael-ferry.com/assets/accordion3.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("http://michael-ferry.com/assets/accordion3.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("http://michael-ferry.com/assets/accordion3.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url("http://michael-ferry.com/assets/accordion3.jpg");
}

.accordion ul:hover li:hover {
  width: 50%;
}

.accordion ul:hover li:hover a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.accordion ul:hover li:hover a * {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3wbvutw/

Comment: See if this solves your problem, by using pseudo elements: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289643/how-do-i-unskew-background-image-in-skewed-layer-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to manage it using the method I spoke before in comment.
Basically, I used `::before` pseudo-elements to put the background image and then unskewed them.

Check it out:

```css
/* +++++++++++++++ NEW INFORMATION ++++++++++++++ */

.accordion ul li::before {
  content: "";
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  background-image: url(http://michael-ferry.com/assets/accordion3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%) skewX(20deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: #FFAE00;
}

.accordion ul {
  width: 90%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 100%;
}

.accordion ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 250px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  float: none;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion ul li div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion ul li div a {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 37vw;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 55px 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: -53px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.accordion ul li div a * {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion ul li div a h2 {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-overflow: clip;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: unset;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  top: 165px;
}

.accordion ul li div a p {
  top: 165px;
  font-size: 13.5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.accordion ul:hover li:hover {
  width: 50%;
}

.accordion ul:hover li:hover a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.accordion ul:hover li:hover a * {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`transform:SkewX` does not work in a way of addition/deduction , it is more like skew X TO Y degree from the original picture.

In order for you to undo the transformation , you have to use `transform: unset;"
I added the following code in your fiddle, it had worked for me.(This also have a -webkit- version)Refer to: [Remove applied CSS transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517464/remove-applied-css-transformation)

```
.accordion ul li {
transform: unset;
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want your text remain skewed, add a class on the on the text and use `:not()` selector

Comment: But then it loses the skew.

Comment: To be honest, I dont fully understand what the "box" meants in the question" is it the rectangle the is under the picture or the text that appears

Comment: Can't find the transform unset thing, it didn't work for me :/

Comment: I've put 4 boxes next to eachother with skewX(-20deg). The image in the box has the same skew as the box. I want the image to not get skewed as the boxes.When I set skewX(20deg) to the images, which should actually put the image in skewX(0), it wont work..