# how to modify svg path data with transform matrix

Tags: css, svg

I have this path:

```
<path 
  d="M 7883.4635415 13741.015625 L 8147.5260415 14725.0" 
  transform="matrix(0.03,0,0,-0.03,0,842)"
/>
```

is it possible to somehow remove the transform and instead modify the points in the path (`d="M 7883.4635415 13741.015625 L 8147.5260415 14725.0"`) directly? I want to animate an element along the path and the transform is causing some issues with offsets.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined

Comment: M 236.5 605.49 L244.42 597.6

Answer (score 0):

This article has good info:

https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/

You can change the `path` in css like this:

```
path
{
   d: path("M 7883.4635415 13741.015625 L 8147.5260415 14725.0")
}
```

To remove transform:

[Remove applied CSS transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517464/remove-applied-css-transformation)

```
transform: unset;
```